# adding a download link to a magnify popup image gallery

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a download link or image source right next to my title after user clicks on thumbnail?

so far I have managed to get the popup working however i can not seem to be able to create a download like to go with my image.

the code below is what i have so far.

```
<div class="product-thumb">
  <a href="images/product-image7.jpg" class="image-popup" title="screenprinting">
    <img src="images/product-image7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="product-info">
      <div class="product-item">
        <h3>PRODUCT1</h3>
        <p>Size / Size / Size</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>P50</span>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the `download` attribute on the [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: I tried it out ,still doesn't seem to work. I even went to the "magnific popup" website and followed the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a download="picture.jpg" href="/path/to/your/picture" title="pictureName">
    <img alt="" src="/path/to/your/picture">
</a>
```

Not supported on every browsers

Comment: the download works fine ,now the issue is that it doesn't popup the image. goes straight to downloading.I appreciate the help everyone